# Using std::stable_sort with a array of pointer to functions

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, function-pointers

I'm trying to implement a class which i can use to sort a list of files based on some different functions of sort.
I'm having trouble to use an array of pointer to function to make calls.

FileList.hpp :

```
class FileList
{
public:
enum sortStyle{EXTENSION, NAME, SIZE, DURATION, PATH};
//...
};

namespace SortFiles
{
    struct  sortFcts{
        FileList::sortStyle sort;
    bool (*fonc)(const FileData &, const FileData &);
    };
    bool                  sortExtension(const FileData &a, const FileData &b);
    bool                  sortName(const FileData &a, const FileData &b);
    bool                  sortDuration(const FileData &a, const FileData &b);
    bool                  sortSize(const FileData &a, const FileData &b);
    bool                  sortPath(const FileData &a, const FileData &b);
}

struct SortFiles::sortFcts tabSortFctsFileList[5] = {{FileList::EXTENSION, &SortFiles::sortExtension}, 
                              {FileList::NAME, &SortFiles::sortName},
                              {FileList::SIZE, &SortFiles::sortSize},
                              {FileList::DURATION, &SortFiles::sortDuration},
                              {FileList::PATH, &SortFiles::sortPath}};
```

FileList.cpp :

```
void                FileList::sort(FileList::sortStyle a)
{
    //std::stable_sort((this->_data).begin(), (this->_data).end(), SortFiles::sortPath);
    std::stable_sort((this->_data).begin(), (this->_data).end(), tabSortFctsFileList[a]);
}
```

Where tabSortFctsFileList[] is just a tab of my struct where i put all my sorting methods.
My problem here is that if I use the commented way it works, but when i use the array i have a compilation error I don't know why. I know i can use a huge switch and it'll work fine but i don't want to.

Here's one of the line of the error message :

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:
 In instantiation of ‘void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<FileData*, std::vector<FileData> >; _Compare = SortFiles::sortFcts]’:

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:3510:49:  
 required from ‘void std::__inplace_stable_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<FileData*, std::vector<FileData> >; _Compare = SortFiles::sortFcts]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5710:52: 
 required from ‘void std::stable_sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<FileData*, std::vector<FileData> >; _Compare = SortFiles::sortFcts]’
FileList.cpp:71:88:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2159:29: error: no match for call to ‘(SortFiles::sortFcts) (FileData&, FileData&)’
if (__comp(*__i, *__first))
```

I feel like the problem here is that I shouldn't use a (*fonc) but rather a fonc as last parameter, but I already tried to do something like : *(Tab[a]) but it says i have no match for operator*.
What should I do to fix it ?

Comment: We need full code. In particular, definition of tabSortFctsFileList.

Comment: `tabSortFctsFileList[a]` you mean `tabSortFctsFileList[a].fonc`?

Comment: I just realized it .. Thanks for that ! I just changed to *(tabSortFctsFileList[a].fonc) and it worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass an object of type `sortFcts` as the predicate parameter of `std::stable_sort()`. Objects are type `sortFcts` are not callable, though. There are two simple fixes:

1. The simpler [and recommended] fix is to just get the `fonc` member of the object:

   ```
   ... tabSortFctsFileList[a].fonc ...
   ```
2. Make objects of type `sortFcts` callable as a predicate by adding a suitable function call operator:

   ```
   struct sortFcts {
       // ...
       bool operator()(const FileData &a, const FileData &b) const {
           return this->fonc(a, b);
       }
   };
   ```

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly what i was looking for